# Combinatory Categorial Grammar (комбинаторная категориальная грамматика) developments and lexicon for Russian language?

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, software, russian

I am trying to apply Cornell Semantic Parsing framwork https://github.com/cornell-lic/spf (implementation of Combinatory Categorial Grammars CCG) to Russian language. This framework takes natural language texts, learns grammar and translates those texts into logical expressions (lambda calculus) that are useful for natural language processing.

My question is - are there some developments of CCG for Russian language? Google gives almost nothing fundamental, only some examples are considered. But I searched only resources in English language. Maybe there are good developments and efforts that are available only in Russian language? I would be happy to hear about them.

What is general consensus about applicability of CCG to Russian/Slavic language? Russian has very rich inflection forms and very uncertain word order (inflection creates big part of meaning), so, this can be complex. But maybe there are efforts still?

Any ideas and hints are welcome. It would be nice to continue already existing efforts and not to reinvent everything from scratch.

Comment: there seem to even lack the public and automatic parsing the words to its different sub-parts, so even mere extraction of ending would be fuzzy. https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/14675/9058
You may try contacting automatic translators developers and asking them for their experience. Maybe some of them would manage to discuss without NDA, I know two stand-alone translators now - translate.ru and dicter.ru Years ago there also was very nice "Сократ Переводчик" but it is long abandoned and it is not known who ever deveoped it. Spell-checkers maybe too have potentially knowledgable guys.

Comment: @Arioch for parsing words to their different subparts consider Yandex mystem. Also there is a rather extensive list of NLP tools maintained by a group of Russian linguists at [nlppub.ru](https://nlpub.ru/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7). Though I do not see any mention of the Cornell Framework or CCGs in general there.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov interesting. There seems to be no online-available installation of mystem, only source tarballs

Comment: Excellent list of excellent resources, thx Dmitri.

Comment: Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/23316/combinatory-categorial-grammar-developments-and-lexicon-for-german-language